# MongoDB ListCollectionNames require authentication in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, authentication

I am implementing a system in C#, where MongoDB is used. The system may involve several homogeneous subsystems that records data. I don't want the subsystems to interfere with each other, so each subsystem creates and operates on its own collection named after its own id. While, the number and names of the subsystems are user-defined throw the UI of the main program.

In order to visualize the data, I need to know how many subsystems are created and what they (their ids) are. I used the following method

```cs
database.ListCollectionNames().ToList<string>()
```

but an exception raised saying the `ListCollectionNames` requires authentications.

I'm pretty sure I granted the program full permissions, while all the collections and even the database is created by the program (so it should be the owner), so I have no idea why this exception is still raised.

I have one possible solution that I can create a separate collection called "ids" who records all the ids of subsystems and I can just fetch the list of names from this collection. But I don't think it necessary, there must be a better solution.

Could anyone explain why this authentication exception is raised and whether there is a way to handle the issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what your connection string?